# Node / Express CORS POST gives 504 and 403

Tags: node.js, macos, express, post, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a very simple server which I can run locally and hit from another server on the web using my IP.

I got my IP from https://www.whatismyip.com/

It lists 2 addresses - Local & IPv4. The local works fine when I send a POST from postman. I see my log in the terminal `request from: chrome-extension://fdmmgi...`

But it doesn't work when I send a POST from another server on the web - I don't see any log in the terminal, and my log on the other server shows `403 Forbidden`

The IPv4 address doesn't work from either postman or the server. Postman says `the response status was 0.` and the log from the other server says `504 gateway time-out`

Which IP should I be using to hit this with a POST from another server? Also what can I change in my local server code (below) to get that working?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port = 3000;


app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {

  // allow any origin
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.use('/', router);

router.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({message: 'Hello, welcome to my server'});
});


router.post('/api/my/endpoint', (request, response) => {
  console.log('request from: ' + request.headers.origin);

  // trying agian to force cors to work
  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.headers.origin);

  response.json({message: 'hi, welcome to my server'});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is behind a network router, other server on internet may can't access to you via public IPv4. You can set up NAT or DMZ host on your router if it supports.

If you send your requests from another server, you don't need CORS, because the same origin policy is only in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using ngrok https://github.com/bubenshchykov/ngrok/